# logical problem in mailing a HTML File

Tags: java

I want to send and HTML file using JSP. But the problem is..
1) When we develop any HTML File we mention some CSS and JavaScript files.
2) So, when i am sending the file, it is missing all the format what i defined in other page(in form of CSS and javascript).
3) So, now I want to implement such a logic by which, it can read all the CSS and JavaScript file and send it with mail together.
4) With same file position and structure. That is, i want to maintain the directory position of CSS and JavaScript.
5) It is possible, but for this i would have to send the CSS/JS file also.That thing i don't want to do explicitly.

Some possible solution what i thought before asking here.......
a) I can add all CSS/JS contents in HTML file, so that it will go with html file at the single time.
b) But it is ok with one or two file. But if I have plenty of files in my website then I would have to copy this content in all file which i don't want.
c) zip all the file together and mail it. But, it also i don't want. I want to mail only .HTML file.
d) I can read HTML file and read the file which has included or added in HTML and mail it implicityly. but in this case, directory structure will not be mentened.

I know it is different type of question. I don't want the code. I just want the logic..
Plz help me...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you pretty much ruled out almost every option. If you only want to send the .html then you'll need to include the .js and the .css in the file.

The only other thing I can think of is to upload the .js, and .css files somewhere else and include references to their locations in the .html.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer has an option to package up the page including all its resources into a single file.

*File -> Save As...*

and then in the *Type* field choose *"Web Archive, single file (*.mht)"*.

Depending on which browser the recipient is using, they may or may not be able to directly view the resulting *.mht file.

Edit: Google's Chrome browser also has a "Save Page As... Web Page, Complete" option which appears to embed the CSS and JS in the HTML file, but not the images. Maybe this would work for you.